# Convert inner join to stored procedure and their performance impact

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

```
select pa.PRODUCT_ID,a.IDENTIFIER,av.DATA, avd.value from PRODUCTATTRIBUTE pa
inner join ATTR a  on a.ATTR_ID = pa.ATTR_ID
inner join ATTRVAL av  on av.ATTRVAL_ID = pa.ATTRVAL_ID
inner join ATTRVALDESC avd   on avd.ATTRVAL_ID = av.ATTRVAL_ID
inner join PRODUCT p on p.PRODUCT_ID= pa.CATENTRY_ID and p.PRODUCTTYPE_ID = 'Product'  and p.DELETED = 0
where a.IDENTIFIER = 'Ordered' and avd.VALUE = '$input' and avd.LANGUAGE_ID=-11

> **Table              - Columns**
> 
> PRODUCTATTRIBUTE   - PRODUCT_ID, ATTR_ID and ATTRVAL_ID
> 
> ATTR               - ATTR_ID, IDENTIFIER
> 
> ATTRVAL            - ATTRVAL_ID , ATTR_ID, DATA   ATTRVALDESC        -
> ATTRVAL_ID, VALUE, LANGUAGE_ID
> 
> PRODUCT            - PRODUCT_ID and some other non-relevant columns
```

The query return multiple rows.

What will be the stored procedure of above Query in DB2(V10.5)?

What will be the difference between the two methods in terms of execution time(
stored procedure and joins)?

Comment: You think a stored procedure is an alternative to joins? It is not - a stored procedure can use SQL and SQL-PL as well as other programming languages to implement additional logic in addition to SQL queries.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher What if the business logic can be achieved by joining 20 tables. Shouldn't I consider a stored procedure instead of 20 joins ?

Comment: @noone this question does not make any sense -- there is nothing about a stored procedure that "solves the problem" of having to make 20 joins.  But who cares about 20 joins? DB2 should be able to handle that just fine.  Doing lots of inner joins is exactly what SQL is designed to do quickly.

Comment: If you think of "programming" a join instead of using SQL - DO NOT do it